# TFS Continuous Build - MSBuild - Running Test fails when search Config files

Tags: tfs, msbuild, mstest

I'm having a little problem with Running Test  on **VS TFS 2008 Continuous Build**.
The problem is that MSTest.exe search config file under 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio  9.0\Common7\IDE\" path, so the error is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\MyConfig.config could not be found.

There is a way  to  specify to MSTest.exe where found config files?

How I can specify that in the  TFSBuild.proj?

My TFSBuild.proj file  contains  these settings:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RunTest>true</RunTest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MetaDataFile Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../MyProj.Complete.vsmdi">
   <TestList>Continuous  Integration Test</TestList>
   <RunConfigFile>$(SolutionRoot)\LocalTestRun.testrunconfig</RunConfigFile>
  </MetaDataFile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use [DeploymentItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute(VS.80).aspx) in your Unit Tests code. So you can control what files and where are deployed during a test run. For example:

```
[DeploymentItemAttibute("MyConfig.config", "MyConfig.config")]
[TestMethod]
(...)
```

This will copy MyConfig.config file to the current directory before a test run.
Hope that helps,